# Ruby- How do you create a stringwith a fixed number of characters?

Tags: ruby, string, loops, variables, for-loop

I am trying to create a variable which is a character string and loop it such that for each index 1 to 1163 it is defined as "modslice" followed by the index number, but always formatted with 4 digits. For example

```
for i in 1..1163
  modslice[i] <- "modslice[i]" 
end
#    such that this i here ^ always has four digits
```

so the string should go

```
modslice0000
modslice0001
modslice0002
#...all the way to
modslice1163
```

Comment: Where does `modslice0000` come from - is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

.............................

```
"modslice[%04d]" % i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word = "modslice0000"
n = 1163

n.times.map { w = word.dup; word.next!; w }
  #=> ["modslice0000", "modslice0001","modslice0002", "modslice0003", "modslice0005",
  #    ...
  #    "modslice1159", "modslice1160", "modslice1161", "modslice1162", "modslice1163"]
```

or

```
[word.dup].concat (n-1).times.map { word.next!.dup }
```

Comment: Downvote was probably because I overlooked the first term (now fixed). Me, I would have just left a comment, then deleted the comment when the oversight was corrected.

Comment: The question is ambiguous in that regard.

Comment: @Stefan, I'm surprised you didn't suggest a modification along the lines of my edit.